# Login to website using raw data from code

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

So I login to a website in my browser and capture the fiddler raw request which looks something like below -

```
GET http://abc.com/getsomething
Host: abc.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: abc.com/somelink
Cookie: snip
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And here is the raw response back -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Sun, 28 Jul 2013 12:06:22 GMT
Content-Length: 67904
//and some HTML
```

I need to extract the HTML from the response. I tried C# HttpWebRequest, WebClient, tried logging in by posting the username and password but it won't go thru.

Is there a C# class that takes the raw request as string input and returns raw output so I don't have to worry about setting the properties individually like headers, cookie etc.?

Comment: Have you tried adding only the cookie header?

Comment: *curtsey* my pleasure!